# Are apps developed for iOS 4.3 compatible with 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, ios5.1

Apparently the latest version of iOS is 5.1. I have been developing an iPad app for the past few months. So I have an iMac with Snow Leopard. Nowadays it seems that iOS 5.1 is the latest version for the iPad.

My question is if the app I have developed for iOS 4.3 is still compatible with iOS 5.1...?

I also realized I should update my iMac to OS Lion in order to be able to install XCode 4.3.2? This is the only version that supports iOS 5.1?

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All iOS versions are backwards-compatible.

Yes. You need the new xcode to use the iOS 5.1 SDK.

Comment: Great, thanks. So my work is not lost. :) Are there any changes as of the way of coding between the two?

Comment: All that is changed is the new API's they have added and the addition of the ARC compiler which can memory-manage for you, should you choose to turn it on.

Comment: Wow shit.. A memory manager! Been hoping for that for ages. Great. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Have fun programming!